# Фон со звездами. Градиентом

Tags: css

Всем здравствуйте.

Я недавно начал заниматься градиентами. Но попал в интернете на картинку фона созданную с помощью градиента. Подскажите, как такое можно градиентом сделать. Весь мозг уже поломал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои попытки:

```css
.super-star {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(126deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) -70px 43px, linear-gradient( 54deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) 30px 43px, linear-gradient( 18deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) 30px 43px, linear-gradient(162deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) -70px 43px, linear-gradient(234deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) -70px 23px, linear-gradient(-54deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) 30px 23px, linear-gradient(126deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) -20px 93px, linear-gradient( 54deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) 80px 93px, linear-gradient( 18deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) 80px 93px, linear-gradient(162deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) -20px 93px, linear-gradient(234deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) -20px 73px, linear-gradient(-54deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) 80px 73px;
  background-color: #232927;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="super-star">
</div>
```

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#stars

Comment: и несколько других паттернов на css3 http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

Comment: @Heidel, о, благодарю. Можете добавить код ответом и я приму

Comment: Ох, жесть какая строка. Переносить нельзя в css?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вы о чём?

Comment: @VAndreew четвёртая строка в вашем коде )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, строка настоящего программиста :D

Comment: Перечитал, действительно непонятно. Строка очень длинная. Переносы строк css поддерживает в таком случае?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да. У меня изначально и было перенесено, но я нажал "Выровнять код" и оно всё в одну ушло, а переносить опять - лень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всё правильно, но вы не так указали направления градиентов

```css
.super-star {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(324deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) -70px 43px, linear-gradient( 36deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) 30px 43px, linear-gradient( 72deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) 30px 43px, linear-gradient(288deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) -70px 43px, linear-gradient(216deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) -70px 23px, linear-gradient(144deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) 30px 23px, linear-gradient(324deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) -20px 93px, linear-gradient( 36deg, #232927 4%, transparent 4%) 80px 93px, linear-gradient( 72deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) 80px 93px, linear-gradient(288deg, #e3d7bf 8.5%, transparent 8.5%) -20px 93px, linear-gradient(216deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) -20px 73px, linear-gradient(144deg, #e3d7bf 7.5%, transparent 7.5%) 80px 73px;
  background-color: #232927;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="super-star">
</div>
```

Comment: Не хорошо воровать код из комментариев, милейший :)

Comment: @Yuri, я ничего не воровал. Нашёл по картинке в интернете!

Comment: Ну ладно, считайте, что я поверил :)

Comment: @Yuri зато тут код, а не ссылки)

Answer (score 0):

Фон со звездами http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#stars и несколько других css3 паттернов http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/